# Python Pandas: create new column with min values based on unique identifiers in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'person':['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'], 
              'bank':['chase', 'bod', 'chase', 'boa', 'chase', 'bod', 'chase', 'boa'],
              'amount': [100, 80, 90, 60, 150, 111, 524, 51]})
```

[image]

Assuming there could be many people in the "person" column. But there are only "chase" and "boa" in the "bank" column. Every person will have both "chase" and "boa". For each person, I want to get the minimum number in the "amount" column for each bank. The output will be like this:

[image]

Each row should have the person, min amount in chase ("chase_min") and min amount in boa ("boa_min").

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I posted the code. The image is just for people to see the table in an easier way. The issue is, as stated above, to select min amount for each user and bank and put them into new columns. Thanks!

Comment: _The issue is, as stated above..._ Isn’t that the goal/objective?

Comment: If you read my post, you can see that I am trying to find a way to make the table in picture 1 into picture 2. But I need some help on how to make the conversion. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies if my comment wasn’t clear, I was asking for the problem/obstacle, not the goal/objective.

Comment: Hi AMC, thank you for your quick response. The obstacle is that for each person and bank combination in the original dataframe, I do not know how to get the minimum value in the column "amount". And make a new dataframe that there is only one row for each person, and each bank's minimum amount is in a new column. I hope this makes it more clear. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: It sounds like a grouping operation, take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html.

Comment: Yes, groupby function is definitely part of the solution. Finding the min "amount" for each person and bank is pretty straightforward. The struggle for me is after finding the min how to change the structure of the dataframe and turn it into the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min() as the aggfunc for a pivot table.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='person', columns=['bank'], values='amount', aggfunc='min')
```

Comment: Can you share what the result looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think the current answer is overkill, and this solution has the advantage of producing a convenient index:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'person': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'],
                   'bank': ['chase', 'bod', 'chase', 'boa', 'chase', 'bod', 'chase', 'boa'],
                   'amount': [100, 80, 90, 60, 150, 111, 524, 51]})

res = df.groupby(["person", "bank"]).min()

print(f"{df}\n\n{res}")
```

Output:

```
  person   bank  amount
0      x  chase     100
1      x    bod      80
2      x  chase      90
3      x    boa      60
4      y  chase     150
5      y    bod     111
6      y  chase     524
7      y    boa      51

              amount
person bank         
x      boa        60
       bod        80
       chase      90
y      boa        51
       bod       111
       chase     150
```